# save axios api response data into a local file as .csv

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, csv

it is possible to save the axios api response into a local file ?
I have this piece of code:

```
axios.get(
        "http://url-to-provide-data.com",
        {headers}
      )
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data);
        responseData(response.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error.response.data);
      });
  }
```

I am trying to use `json2csv` in ordwer to save the api response into a local file as csv but not really working or better said, I'm not really sure how to use'it, any help is much appreciated !

Comment: Show how you tried with `json2csv` please.

Comment: @tauzN try {
  const csv = parse(reportData);
  console.log("CSV", csv);
} catch (err) {
  console.error(err);
}